# How to fix/"lock" the y-axis-scale in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale, axis, yaxis

I want to compare 5 plots (barplots with frequencies overlayed by a temperature line graph), for that the y scale must be constant in all the graphs. But when I plot the graphs, then the y-scale adapts according to the maximum y-value (= the max. frequency) of each dataset. 
This is my code:

```
ggplot(df) + 
    geom_bar(aes(hours,count), stat = "identity", fill = "gray92", colour = 
"gray92") +
    geom_line(aes(hours, percipitation*14), stat = "identity", size = 1.2) +
    theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
          panel.background = element_blank(),
          axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) +
    ylab("Frequency") +
    ylim(0,80) +
    scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~./14, name = "Percipitation [mm]"), breaks = seq(0,80,10)) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0:23)) +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 42, face = "bold", hjust = 0.5, margin = margin(0,0,35,0), 
          axis.title.x = element_text(size = 32, margin = margin(20,0,0,0),
          axis.title.y = element_text(size = 32, margin = margin(0,15,0,0)
          axis.title.y.right = element_text(size = 32, margin = margin(0,0,0,15), 
          axis.text.x = element_text(size = 18, margin = margin(7,0,0,0),
          axis.text.y = element_text(size = 18, margin = margin(0,5,0,0)),
          axis.text.y.right = element_text(size = 18, margin = margin(0,0,0,5)))
```

I want that all graphs have a y-scale:from 0 to 80, regardless of the maximum value of the actual dataset.

Thank u! :)

Comment: I'd also suggest using a facet to plot this if possible, since it fixes axes by default

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your scale_y_continuous is overriding the ylim() you set the line before, try this instead:

```
scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~./14, name = "Precipitation [mm]"), 
breaks = seq(0,80,10),limits = c(0,80))
```